# Interpretation of python split used in code

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python 3 and trying to understand this line as it relates to the path below

```
    path = event['path'].split('/',2)[2]

    I know the split just splits the path with the /.

    what does .split('/',2)[2] imply ?


    path = event['path'].split('/',2)[2]
    destination_url = f"https://bamboo:7676/watch/superDb/v3.0/solution/{path}"
```

Comment: Besides the delimiter, the split() method accepts a limiter - the number of times a split should occur. in your case, the split on '/' is limited to two splits within the string

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `str.split` is `maxsplit` and is explain by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as:

> If `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements). If `maxsplit` is not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

In the case of `.split('/',2)`, split will split the given string for each `/` that it finds, but it will stop after at most 2 splits. I.e. there will be at most 3 results at the end.

For example:

```
In [1]: example_url = "www.example.com/my/cool/url"

In [2]: example_url.split('/',2)
Out[2]: ['www.example.com', 'my', 'cool/url']
```